# gob.Register name not registered for interface in another package

Tags: go, gob, go-interface

I have recently restructured my code so that now under the `main` package there are two packages: `chain` and `api`.

In `chain` I defined a few structs `SomeStruct1`, `SomeStruct2` and an interface `SomeInterface` for those structs. The following is what `chain/cli.go` looks like.

```
package chain

type CLI struct{}

func (cli *CLI) Run() {
    ...
    gob.Register(SomeStruct1{})
    gob.Register(SomeStruct2{})
    ...
}
```

There is another similar `api/api.go` where inside `Run()` I put `gob.Register(chain.SomeStruct1{})`.

`main.go` looks like this:

```
package main

import (
    "myproj/api"
    "myproj/chain"
)

func main() {
    // I have also tried the following lines.
    // gob.Register(chain.SomeStruct1{})
    // gob.Register(chain.SomeStruct2{})
    go api.Run()

    cli := chain.CLI{}
    cli.Run()
}
```

However, I got the error `gob: name not registered for interface: "main.SomeStruct1"` at runtime. This did not happen when I had all the code inside one `main` package and I felt weird that `SomeStruct1` is now under `chain` package but the error referred to `main.SomeStruct1`. Where did I get wrong of `gob.Register()`?

Comment: try to put the `go.Register()` statement on `init()` function

Comment: putting `gob.Register()` in `init()` didn't work. I also tried putting gob.Register() on the line right before decoder.Decode(), but the same error persisted. I think the underlying problem is that `chain.someStruct1` is somehow identified as `main.someStruct1`.

Comment: as a workaround, I am now using gob.RegisterName("main.SomeStruct1", chain.SomeStruct1) and things seem to work fine for now

Comment: I suggest please post the solution as an answer, then approve it. it might be useful for others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not been able to solve the problem completely and I think the cause was that `chain.SomeStruct1` was somehow recognized at runtime as having the name `main.SomeStruct1` while it was registered with the internal name `main.SomeStruct1`.

Therefore a workaround I have now is using `gob.RegisterName("main.SomeStruct1", chain.SomeStruct1)`.